# When to use grep, less, awk, sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep, less

I'm entering the world of Linux and at work I'm using `grep` more and more.  By doing that I'm figuring out that sometimes it's not adequate for what I want.

I was struggling with `grep` a few days ago and a colleague of mine who is a senior Linux admin, told me to use `awk`. I was stunned by how fast I got a result.

So my question is when do you choose to use one over the other? What questions can I ask myself before going to work with `grep` and spending a lot of time, when I could have done it with `awk` and saved time?

Comment: This is a good question but it really is very broad and primarily opinion based. To answer your question, using grep as opposed to awk really depends on how comfortable you are using awk/sed. There are a few reasons why one would use this over the latter such as looking for something more specific than what grep has to offer or if you are attempting to replace/edit files with a specific string (using sed). But again, all depends on your comfort level and experience with using awk/sed.

Comment: Use `less` to _view_ a file. Use `grep` to _search_ through a file. Use `sed` to _edit_ a file. Use `awk` over `grep` and `sed` when the file you want to process has some kind of _structure_ (such as columns). Use `sed` over `awk` when you mainly want to deal with lines (such as delete or add lines of text). I'm sure somebody will write a 20-pages answer that is more complete than mine.

Comment: Hi Sato, It not about the length, but what is said. And you few lines are very informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`sed` and `awk` are supersets of `grep`, there are things that are easier to do with one or the other.

`grep foo` can be written `sed '/foo/!d'` or `awk /foo/`, but consider:

`grep -i foo` would have to be `sed '/[fF][oO][oO]/!d'` unless you want to consider non-standard extensions like GNU's `sed '/foo/I!d'`. Or with `awk`: `awk 'tolower($0) ~ /foo/'` or again using a GNU extension: `awk -v IGNORECASE=1 /foo/`.

Things the different tools are good at and cumbersome with the other tools:

#### grep

`grep` is a simple tool but has very specialised modes of operation that are harder to reproduce with `awk` or `sed`:

- `grep -i` for case insensitive matching (see above)
- `grep -Fe "$string"` for fixed string search (`export string; awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["string"])'` with `awk`, no direct equivalent with `sed`).
- (non standard) `grep -r` for recursive search
- (non standard) `grep -P`/`pcregrep` for perl-like regexps (some `sed` implementations have perl-like regexp support though not the most major ones)
- (non standard) `grep -o` to return the matched portion (several lines of `awk` or `sed` to do the same)
- (non standard) `grep -A/B/C` to return context around the match (again painful to do in a similar fashion with `sed` or `awk`)

#### sed

- `s/foo/bar/`: `sed`'s `s` command has features that are hard to implement in `awk` like:
- `s/foo\(.*\)bar/\1/g`: capturing (though GNU awk has a `gensub()` extension for that)
- `s/foo/bar/3`: replace the 3rd occurrence on each line
- (non-standard): in-place file editing (though it's also supported by GNU `awk` now).

#### awk

`awk` is the most feature rich of the three.

- good for dealing with numbers
- good for dealing with input formatted in columns.
- good for extracting and combining data from different sources, with its associative arrays.

#### perl

`perl` as a practical extraction and reporting tool has the best of all those. That's what it was initially designed for (to be the tool that makes all those `sed`/`awk` obsolete).

Mastering `perl` to do text processing does give a serious advantage. I'd recommend spending some time on it, even before looking at the less common `sed` commands for instance.

#### performance

As a rule of thumb, the more specialised the tool, the most efficient it is at the task. But that also very much depends on the implementation, the task and a few other factors and performance can have trade-offs that may need to be taken into account.

For instance, there are some `grep` or `sed` implementations that are very fast, but for instance they don't support multibyte characters so can only work correctly on US-English text in multi-byte locales. Or they're fast because they work on a small fixed-length buffer and thus can't work on arbitrary input...

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you know about the efficiency of the tools? I'm confused about the OP's statement, that `awk` is much faster than `grep`.

Comment: @pfnuesel, that very much depends on the implementation and on the usage pattern. For instance, `mawk` is known to be very efficient (but doesn't support multibyte characters which is part of the reason it's more efficient than some other tools)

Comment: @pfnuesel I think the OP is saying they were able to write the command they needed quickly with awk vs how long they had been struggling to write such a command with grep, not that the command they wrote executed faster with awk than grep.