# How well does grep/sed/awk perform on very large files?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep, performance

I was wondering if grep, sed, and awk were viable tools for finding data in very large files.

Lets say I have a 1TB file. If i wanted to process the text in that file, what would the time frame look like if i used the individual commands grep, sed, and awk, as well as mixing them together.

Obviously a specific answer is not possible since the results will vary based on hardware specs, but if i could get a general estimation that would be helpful.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303044/when-to-use-grep-less-awk-sed might help

Comment: Something that can have a very large influence: if you know that the file contains only 7bit ASCII, set LANG=C (as opposed to some .utf8 string) in the environment before running the command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally I would say `grep` is the fastest one, `sed` is the slowest. Of course this depends on what are you doing exactly. I find `awk` much faster than `sed`.

You can speed up grep if you don't need real regular expressions but only simple fixed strings (option -F).

If you want to use grep, sed, awk together in pipes, then I would place the grep command first if possible.

For example this:

```
grep -F "foo" file | sed -n 's/foo/bar/p'
```

is usually faster than this:

```
sed -n 's/foo/bar/p' file
```

Although the `grep` in the first line seems unnecessary.

BTW you may speed up these commands using `LC_ALL=C` if you are dealing with simple ASCII text files.

Note all my experience is based on the gnu commands. You may also try different implementations and compare the speed.